# Convert JSON to DataSet with TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter

Tags: json, rest, delphi, dataset, converters

I need to consume a REST API that returns a JSON that resembles the following:

```
[
    {
        "purchaseCode": 1,
        "totalItems": 5,
        "totalPrice": 5102.04,
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "name": "Michael Jennette",
            "country": "Brazil",
            "state": "São Paulo",
            "postCode": "16",
            "landmark": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "purchaseCode": 2,
        "totalItems": 3,
        "totalPrice": 4312.65,
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "name": "David Samuel",
            "country": "Brazil",
            "state": "São Paulo",
            "postCode": "40",
            "landmark": ""
        }
    }
]
```

I can easily convert this JSON format to a class using TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue. The problem is that I need to print reports with this json's data. So it's more interesting to convert JSON to DataSet.

Before JSON existed, XML was heavily used. In XMLs that an object owned another object, the DataSet had to have a field of type DataSet that would be referenced by another DataSet. This way it is possible to convert all XML to DataSet.

I'm trying to do the same with JSON using the native component TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter. I have seen that I can specify the fields for ResponseDataSetAdapter and that each field can have "child fields".

Therefore, I defined "deliveryAddress" as the DataSet type and specified its "child fields". But when I run the request, I get an "Invalid Argument" error and then another "Invalid value for field "deliveryAddress" error.

Is it possible to convert this JSON format to DataSet using TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter? If yes, how? Or is there another way? I did not want to have to convert to classes and then manually fill each DataSet.

---

***Sample project:***

***Server (WebBroker)***

**Project1.dpr**

```pascal
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  IPPeerServer,
  IPPeerAPI,
  IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge,
  Web.WebReq,
  Web.WebBroker,
  WebModuleUnit1 in 'WebModuleUnit1.pas' {WebModule1: TWebModule},
  ServerConst1 in 'ServerConst1.pas';

{$R *.res}

function BindPort(Aport: Integer): Boolean;
var
  LTestServer: IIPTestServer;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    LTestServer := PeerFactory.CreatePeer('', IIPTestServer) as IIPTestServer;
    LTestServer.TestOpenPort(APort, nil);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function CheckPort(Aport: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if BindPort(Aport) then
    Result := Aport
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

procedure SetPort(const Aserver: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge; APort: String);
begin
  if not (Aserver.Active) then
  begin
    APort := APort.Replace(cCommandSetPort, '').Trim;
    if CheckPort(APort.ToInteger) > 0 then
    begin
      Aserver.DefaultPort := APort.ToInteger;
      Writeln(Format(sPortSet, [APort]));
    end
    else
      Writeln(Format(sPortInUse, [Aport]));
  end
  else
    Writeln(sServerRunning);
  Write(cArrow);
end;

procedure StartServer(const Aserver: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge);
begin
  if not (Aserver.Active) then
  begin
    if CheckPort(Aserver.DefaultPort) > 0 then
    begin
      Writeln(Format(sStartingServer, [Aserver.DefaultPort]));
      Aserver.Bindings.Clear;
      Aserver.Active := True;
    end
    else
      Writeln(Format(sPortInUse, [Aserver.DefaultPort.ToString]));
  end
  else
    Writeln(sServerRunning);
  Write(cArrow);
end;

procedure StopServer(const Aserver: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge);
begin
  if Aserver.Active  then
  begin
    Writeln(sStoppingServer);
    Aserver.Active := False;
    Aserver.Bindings.Clear;
    Writeln(sServerStopped);
  end
  else
    Writeln(sServerNotRunning);
  Write(cArrow);
end;

procedure WriteCommands;
begin
  Writeln(sCommands);
  Write(cArrow);
end;

procedure WriteStatus(const Aserver: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge);
begin
  Writeln(sIndyVersion + Aserver.SessionList.Version);
  Writeln(sActive + Aserver.Active.ToString(TUseBoolStrs.True));
  Writeln(sPort + Aserver.DefaultPort.ToString);
  Writeln(sSessionID + Aserver.SessionIDCookieName);
  Write(cArrow);
end;

procedure RunServer(APort: Integer);
var
  LServer: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;
  LResponse: string;
begin
  WriteCommands;
  LServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(nil);
  try
    LServer.DefaultPort := APort;
    while True do
    begin
      Readln(LResponse);
      LResponse := LowerCase(LResponse);
      if LResponse.StartsWith(cCommandSetPort) then
        SetPort(LServer, LResponse)
      else if sametext(LResponse, cCommandStart) then
        StartServer(LServer)
      else if sametext(LResponse, cCommandStatus) then
        WriteStatus(LServer)
      else if sametext(LResponse, cCommandStop) then
        StopServer(LServer)
      else if sametext(LResponse, cCommandHelp) then
        WriteCommands
      else if sametext(LResponse, cCommandExit) then
        if LServer.Active then
        begin
          StopServer(LServer);
          break
        end
        else
          break
      else
      begin
        Writeln(sInvalidCommand);
        Write(cArrow);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LServer.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
  if WebRequestHandler <> nil then
    WebRequestHandler.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;
    RunServer(8080);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end
end.
```

**ServerConst1.pas**

```pascal
unit ServerConst1;

interface

resourcestring
  sPortInUse = '- Error: Port %s already in use';
  sPortSet = '- Port set to %s';
  sServerRunning = '- The Server is already running';
  sStartingServer = '- Starting HTTP Server on port %d';
  sStoppingServer = '- Stopping Server';
  sServerStopped = '- Server Stopped';
  sServerNotRunning = '- The Server is not running';
  sInvalidCommand = '- Error: Invalid Command';
  sIndyVersion = '- Indy Version: ';
  sActive = '- Active: ';
  sPort = '- Port: ';
  sSessionID = '- Session ID CookieName: ';
  sCommands = 'Enter a Command: ' + slineBreak +
    '   - "start" to start the server'+ slineBreak +
    '   - "stop" to stop the server'+ slineBreak +
    '   - "set port" to change the default port'+ slineBreak +
    '   - "status" for Server status'+ slineBreak +
    '   - "help" to show commands'+ slineBreak +
    '   - "exit" to close the application';

const
  cArrow = '->';
  cCommandStart = 'start';
  cCommandStop = 'stop';
  cCommandStatus = 'status';
  cCommandHelp = 'help';
  cCommandSetPort = 'set port';
  cCommandExit = 'exit';

implementation

end.
```

**WebModuleUnit1.pas**

```pascal
unit WebModuleUnit1;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Web.HTTPApp;

type
  TWebModule1 = class(TWebModule)
    procedure WebModule1jsonAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  WebModuleClass: TComponentClass = TWebModule1;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1jsonAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  Response.Content :=
    '[{"purchaseCode":1,"totalItems":5,"totalPrice":5102.04,"deliveryAddress":{"name":"Michael Jennette","country":"Brazil","state":"S\u00E3o Paulo","postCode":"16","landmark":""}},' +
    '{"purchaseCode":2,"totalItems":3,"totalPrice":4312.65,"deliveryAddress":{"name":"David Samuel","country":"Brazil","state":"S\u00E3o Paulo","postCode":"40","landmark":""}}]';
end;

end.
```

**WebModuleUnit1.dfm**

```pascal
object WebModule1: TWebModule1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Actions = <
    item
      MethodType = mtGet
      Name = 'json'
      PathInfo = '/json'
      OnAction = WebModule1jsonAction
    end>
  Height = 230
  Width = 415
end
```

***Client***

**Client1.dpr**

```pascal
program Client1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, IPPeerClient, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Param,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  REST.Response.Adapter, REST.Client, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnRequest: TButton;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1: TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter;
    FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable;
    FDMemTable2: TFDMemTable;
    FDMemTable1purchaseCode: TIntegerField;
    FDMemTable1totalItems: TIntegerField;
    FDMemTable1totalPrice: TCurrencyField;
    FDMemTable1deliveryAddress: TDataSetField;
    FDMemTable2name: TStringField;
    FDMemTable2country: TStringField;
    FDMemTable2state: TStringField;
    FDMemTable2postCode: TStringField;
    FDMemTable2landmark: TStringField;
    procedure btnRequestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnRequestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
end;

end.
```

**Unit1.dfm**

```pascal
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 362
  ClientWidth = 724
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object btnRequest: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Request'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btnRequestClick
  end
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 296
    Top = 48
    Width = 409
    Height = 297
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 1
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    Left = 232
    Top = 152
  end
  object RESTClient1: TRESTClient
    Accept = 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,'
    AcceptCharset = 'UTF-8, *;q=0.8'
    BaseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/json'
    Params = <>
    HandleRedirects = True
    RaiseExceptionOn500 = False
    Left = 32
    Top = 64
  end
  object RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest
    Client = RESTClient1
    Params = <>
    Response = RESTResponse1
    SynchronizedEvents = False
    Left = 32
    Top = 112
  end
  object RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Left = 32
    Top = 160
  end
  object RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1: TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter
    Dataset = FDMemTable1
    FieldDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'purchaseCode'
        DataType = ftInteger
      end
      item
        Name = 'totalItems'
        DataType = ftInteger
      end
      item
        Name = 'totalPrice'
        DataType = ftCurrency
      end
      item
        Name = 'deliveryAddress'
        ChildDefs = <
          item
            Name = 'name'
            DataType = ftString
            Size = 150
          end
          item
            Name = 'country'
            DataType = ftString
            Size = 150
          end
          item
            Name = 'state'
            DataType = ftString
            Size = 150
          end
          item
            Name = 'postCode'
            DataType = ftString
            Size = 50
          end
          item
            Name = 'landmark'
            DataType = ftString
            Size = 150
          end>
        DataType = ftDataSet
        Size = 5
      end>
    Response = RESTResponse1
    Left = 32
    Top = 216
  end
  object FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvSilentMode]
    ResourceOptions.SilentMode = True
    UpdateOptions.AssignedValues = [uvCheckRequired]
    UpdateOptions.CheckRequired = False
    Left = 168
    Top = 152
    object FDMemTable1purchaseCode: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'purchaseCode'
    end
    object FDMemTable1totalItems: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'totalItems'
    end
    object FDMemTable1totalPrice: TCurrencyField
      FieldName = 'totalPrice'
    end
    object FDMemTable1deliveryAddress: TDataSetField
      FieldName = 'deliveryAddress'
    end
  end
  object FDMemTable2: TFDMemTable
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvSilentMode]
    ResourceOptions.SilentMode = True
    UpdateOptions.AssignedValues = [uvCheckRequired]
    UpdateOptions.CheckRequired = False
    Left = 168
    Top = 224
    object FDMemTable2name: TStringField
      FieldName = 'name'
      Size = 150
    end
    object FDMemTable2country: TStringField
      FieldName = 'country'
      Size = 150
    end
    object FDMemTable2state: TStringField
      FieldName = 'state'
      Size = 150
    end
    object FDMemTable2postCode: TStringField
      FieldName = 'postCode'
      Size = 50
    end
    object FDMemTable2landmark: TStringField
      FieldName = 'landmark'
      Size = 150
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There are many examples and videos that show the correct usage of the RESTResponseDataSetAdaptor. The most significant thing to note is that statement in the Embarcadero help that says "Please be aware that not every JSON data can be transformed into a DataSet structure." at (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/REST_Client_Library#TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter)